# Strange filter behavior in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following [dataset](http://tinyurl.com/qjtbx3m)

Why do I get different results when doing:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(!(w >= 1 | lag(w >= 1, default = F))) %>% 
  filter(lag(t, default = T) != t) %>%
  summarise(median = median(r), mad = mad(r))
```

Which results in:

```
  median      mad
1    664 142.3296
```

And

```
df %>% 
  filter(!(w >= 1 | lag(w >= 1, default = F)), 
         lag(t, default = T) != t) %>%
  summarise(median = median(r), mad = mad(r))
```

Which gives:

```
  median      mad
1    671 152.7078
```

Comment: I guess, in the first case, the second filter works on the already filtered data, but in the second , `lag(t, default=T)` is working on the original dataset.  So, you are getting `89` and `97` rows respectively.

Comment: The two different methods of filtering your observations gives different data.frames with which to calculate median and mad. 
`%>%` should be read as "then". 

So in the first case you filter with the first condition `filter(!(w >= 1 | lag(w >= 1, default = F)))` filtering everything away that doesn't match the filter, **then** filter the second condition.

In the second case it is one big filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See comments above, as well as: http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html

> `filter()` allows you to select a subset of the rows of a data frame.

...

> `filter()`  works similarly to `subset()` except that you can give it any number of filtering conditions which are joined together with `&` (not `&&` which is easy to do accidentally!). You can use other boolean operators explicitly:
>   `filter(flights, month == 1 | month == 2)`